# MongoDB Concurrency Question - FindOne, then FindOneAndUpdate Atomicity

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, performance, concurrency

I would appreciate your time on answering this question before I commit it to some code.

I've looked through multiple docs on MongoDB and various forums for the answer to this question, however, I would like to know exactly how certain series of operations execute based on my specific circumstances.

Fundamentally, I would like to perform a Read (findOne) operation on a specific document in a collection within its own shard to obtain its current value, modify it, and then store it back into that document (findOneAndUpdate). That sounds easy enough, however, this specific document can potentially get Written upon during the delay between that Read and then Write operation if I understand properly.

For more context, this is a stock market based application. The shard and collection I am referring to here is a user's portfolio which contains information such as the stock ticker, the number of shares owned of that stock, and the total cost they have historically paid for it. The issue here is that when a player sells a share, I have to proportionally adjust the historic total cost by multiplying a ratio of (formerOwnedShares - executedSoldShares)/(formerOwnedShares) where formerOwnedShares is information that needs to be Read, processed, then Updated (i.e. the user currently owns 10 shares and has paid $10 for them over time, they sell 5 shares, now they own 5 shares and have paid $5 to maintain a consistent average cost per share).

I am concerned about the delay between the Read and Update operations. Several other areas of code can operate on this portfolio document from other users (such as other users buying/selling shares with them), so there is a very real possibility that the first Read operation pulls information from an older version of this document that has just recently been updated.

Is there any way to process this sort of situation in one atomic operation in order to maintain perfect concurrency? The issue is clearly the result of having to update a document's value based on that document's most recent value - which I do not think you can do in a single findOneAndUpdate operation.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a transaction with read concern snapshot, which is an implementation of [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), to utilize the same base document version for both operations (find and find-and-modify).

> Is there any way to process this sort of situation in one atomic operation in order to maintain perfect concurrency?

This question makes no sense. First, what do you mean by "perfect concurrency". Second, concurrency is not the same as serialization (in fact, they are exactly opposite).

A baseline approach to performing multiple operations that appear sequential in a concucrrent environment is to 1) maintain a "version" field in the document, 2) upon 2nd and subsequent operations, condition the updates on the version not changing, 3) if updates failed retry the entire process until they succeed.

Transactions with snapshot read concern hopefully automate all of this for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I am fairly new to Transactions, so I am still learning it. When calling for a session, is this effectively putting a "lock" on the current connection to a shard? Let's say multiple sessions are started with a shard, are these sessions essentially being queued up to execute all-or-none in blocks? I am having trouble understanding how it executes honestly.

Comment: No, sessions do not lock. Transactions do not lock either. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control.

Comment: I see. One final question, for example: `const session = client.startSession()
await session.withTransaction(async () => {...`, when starting the session here, what is it effectively doing to the connected shard that allows for multiple atomic queries across several other shards, collections, and so on?

Comment: The session by itself isn't doing much, but the answer to this question doesn't fit in a comment so please ask it in a question of its own.

Comment: You also keep using the word "shard" but 1) if you are starting with a sharded cluster, this only complicates matters and 2) if you arn't in a sharded cluster, the correct term would be "node" of a replica set.